# How to use Scandit plugin in ionic 2

Tags: telerik, ionic2, barcode-scanner

I am trying to scan barcode with Scandit sdk or plugin. How to import scandit plugin in .ts file in ionic2.
My code is

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';

import { BarcodeScanner } from 'ionic-native';

import { Platform } from 'ionic-angular'

declare var Scandit;
declare var picker;

@Component({
selector: 'page-home',
templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {


constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {

}
success(session) {
alert(session.newlyRecognizedCodes[0].data);    
}

failure(error) {
alert("Failed: " + error);    
}

scan()
{
Scandit.License.setAppKey("My key");
var settings = new Scandit.ScanSettings();
settings.setSymbologyEnabled(Scandit.Barcode.Symbology.EAN13, true);
settings.setSymbologyEnabled(Scandit.Barcode.Symbology.UPC12, true);
settings.setSymbologyEnabled(Scandit.Barcode.Symbology.EAN8, true);               
settings.setSymbologyEnabled(Scandit.Barcode.Symbology.CODE39, true);
settings.codeDuplicateFilter = -1;
picker = new Scandit.BarcodePicker(settings);
picker.continuousMode = true;
picker.getOverlayView().setViewfinderDimension(0.9, 0.2, 0.6, 0.2);
picker.setMargins(new Scandit.Margins(0, 0, 0, 200), null, 0);
picker.show(success, null, failure);
picker.startScanning();
}
stop()
{
picker.cancel();
}

start() 
{
picker.startScanning();
picker.setMargins(new Scandit.Margins(0, 0, 0, 200), null, 0.5);
picker.getOverlayView().setViewfinderDimension(0.9, 0.2, 0.6, 0.2);
}

}
```

I write this code based upon this link -   http://krishjan.com/2016/10/27/multiple-barcode-scanning-in-ioniccordova-using-scandit-api/

But it doesn't working. How can I Scan barcode using scandit plugin.

Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solve my problem with importing the plugin into .ts file like this

```
import { Scanditsdk } from plugins/com.mirasense.scanditsdk.plugin/plugin.xml
```

Then it perfectly works.